# XSLT1: convert XML nodes to Html list, by starting from the deepest node first

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this below xml

```
 <root>
        <s>
            <name>self-1</name>
            <parents>
                <s>
                    <name>p-1-2</name>
                    <parents>
                        <s>
                            <name>p-1-2-1</name>
                            <parents>
                                <s>
                                    <name>p-1-2-1-1</name>
                                </s>
                            </parents>
                        </s>
                        <s>
                            <name>p-1-2-2</name>
                        </s>
                    </parents>
                </s>
            </parents>
        </s>
    </root>
```

and I need to write an xslt1 to parse that xml to produce output like below, the goal is to process all parents nodes first and finally the node self-1. Please give me some advice.

```
<ul>
    <li>p-1-2-1-1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>p-1-2-1</li>
        <li>p-1-2-2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>p-1-2</li>
            <ul>
                <!-- self -->
                <li>self-1</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion on how to solve that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::parents[not(s/parents)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parents | root">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="s/name"/>
      <xsl:variable name="p" select="parent::s/parent::parents | parent::s/parent::root"/>
      <xsl:if test="$p">
        <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$p"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:if>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That outputs

```
<ul>
   <li>p-1-2-1-1</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>p-1-2-1</li>
         <li>p-1-2-2</li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li>p-1-2</li>
               <li>
                  <ul>
                     <li>self-1</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

That is not exactly what you asked for, but that is done intentionally: your sample had `ul` elements with `ul` children but that is not allowed in HTML(http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2). So my stylesheet makes sure the result is valid HTML by making sure any `ul` has only `li` child elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, I totally forgot that I could make use of descendant axis

Answer (score 0):

to handle multile node `<s>`

I updated the template `<xsl:template match="parents | root">` to something like below:

```
 <xsl:template match="parents | root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="s/name"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="parent::s/parent::parents">
                    <xsl:variable name="p" select="parent::s/parent::parents"/>
                    <li><xsl:apply-templates select="$p"/></li>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="parent::s/parent::root">
                    <xsl:variable name="p" select="parent::s/parent::root"/>
                    <li><xsl:apply-templates select="$p"/></li>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
```